# Unblur Div On Reveal

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div that I want to unblur as I scroll to it, I have it working right now but it starts to blur at full page height instead of starting when the div comes into view,

jquery here:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      var revealBlur = 50 - Math.floor($(this).scrollTop() / 25);
      if (revealBlur < 0) { revealBlur = 0; }
        $('#content2').css({
        '-webkit-filter': 'blur('+revealBlur+'em)'
      });
});
```

the div is #content2, it's 500px height, is there an easy way to change this code to only start at the point #content2 comes into view? Want it to start really blury and then focus by the time you scroll past 250px of the div height.

This is the jsfiddle showing what it's doing,

https://jsfiddle.net/joshtrose/vr1n8ty7/6/

works perfectly but the jquery is calculating blur all the time, I have a 100vh hero image and when I scroll down it's still calculating blur, only want it to work when the div is in view, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want it to calculate when the div is in view you can use a method to check if it is in the viewport (i.e.: check if the element is actually visible to the user). There are some plain JS ways of doing this as well, but if you want to use jQuery:

```
// From https://medium.com/talk-like/detecting-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-jquery-a6a4405a3ea2
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();
    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();
    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

Then modify your `scroll` event a little bit:

```
// Define myDiv outside of scroll event block
var myDiv = $('#content2');

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if (myDiv.isInViewport()) { // Check if myDiv is in view port
        var revealBlur = 50 - Math.floor($(this).scrollTop() / 25);
        if (revealBlur < 0) { revealBlur = 0; }
        myDiv.css({
            '-webkit-filter': 'blur('+revealBlur+'em)'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works well, I was thinking also is there a way to set the blur of the div to 20em statically, but with a transition of 0.5s and then remove that blur entry when the div comes into view? that way the browser isn't calculating a tonne of blur changes?

Comment: You could probably create a CSS class with that `transition: 0.5s` and `--webkit-filter` on it, then add or remove the class dynamically when the div comes into view. Hard for me to say how that will behave with the `scroll` event but you could start there.

Comment: I just removed the var and if statements for revealBlur and changed blur amount when myDiv is in viewport from +revealBlur+'em to 0em, it works well but only works once, I also changed myDiv.isInViewport()+250) adding 250 so that it unblurs as you pass 250px of the div height, only issue now is it only works once, is there a way to check where I am on the page so if you scroll up and back down it blurs/unblurs again? thanks!

Comment: Sorry its really hard for me to visualize what you mean. I would make another stackoverflow question with a new code example